# MySQL Workbench fails start with plugins

Tags: mysql-workbench

**In few words:**

```
MySQL Workbench does not loading plugins in unknown reason;
```

**More detailed:**

At application start log file contains a lot of errors:

```
17:59:51 [INF][      WBContext]: WbContext::init
17:59:51 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/migration_grt.py
17:59:51 [ERR][         python]: Traceback (most recent call last):
17:59:51 [ERR][         python]:   File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/migration_grt.py", line 23, in <module>
17:59:51 [ERR][         python]:     import migration_main
17:59:51 [ERR][         python]:   File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/migration_main.py", line 26, in <module>
17:59:51 [ERR][         python]:     import migration
17:59:51 [ERR][         python]:   File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/migration.py", line 24, in <module>
17:59:51 [ERR][         python]:     from workbench.log import log_debug
17:59:51 [ERR][         python]: ImportError: No module named log
....
```

and

```
17:59:52 [WRN][        Command]: Plugin item wb.db.copy.open was not found
17:59:52 [WRN][        Command]: Plugin item wb.migration.open was not found
17:59:52 [WRN][        Command]: Plugin item wb.migration.showTypeMapEditor was not found
17:59:52 [WRN][        Command]: Plugin item wb.tools.backupConnections was not found...
...
```

When I start a new connection to the database and select some schema I have no anymore items in context menu like `Drop schema/table`, `Select rows with some limit`, `Copy to clipboard` and so on.
Clicking by `info` icon gives me popup window with text: `Module SQLIDEUtils not found`.

plugins and modules folders are exists on my machine:

```
> ls /usr/share/mysql-workbench/
data                     extras      images              modules                      mysqlwbmeb.py          sshtunnel.py
diagram_size_form.glade  find.glade  input_dialog.glade  mysql.profiles               script_templates       sys
diagram_view.glade       firewall    libraries           mysql_system_status_rmt.vbs  shell_snippets.py.txt  wb.glade
embedded_find.glade      grt         model_view.glade    mysql_system_status.vbs      snippets               workbench.rc
```

**==Versions==**

```
> uname -a
Linux bender 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**==Log file parts==**

```
    18:18:02 [INF][   WBContext UI]: Initializing workbench context UI with these values:
    base dir: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
    plugin path: /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/plugins
    struct path: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt
    module path: /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules
    library path: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/libraries
    user data dir: /home/alex/.mysql/workbench
    open at start: 
    open type: 
    run at startup: 
    run type: 
    Force SW rendering: No
    Force OpenGL: No
    quit when done: No

    ...

    18:20:09 [INF][      WBContext]: System info:
    MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 6.3.4  revision 0 build 828 (64 bit)
    Configuration Directory: /home/alex/.mysql/workbench
    Data Directory: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
    Cairo Version: 1.14.2
    OS: Linux 3.19.0-15-generic
    CPU: 3x AMD Athlon(tm) II X3 450 Processor (3200.000MHz) - 7.80GiB RAM
    Distribution: Ubuntu 15.04

    Fips mode enabled: no
```

Comment: Where did you get the binary and how did you install it? Did you install a custom plugin?

Comment: @Phillip Olson I get it via $ apt-get install mysql-workbench-community and then from download page. No custom plugins

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the problem is. It installs fine for me using the same setup. I'm not sure how best to debug but it feels worthy of a bug report. Please submit one at bugs.mysql.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't believe it. There was installed python package `workbench` with which mysql-workbench was conflicted.

Comment: Similarly, my Visual Studio 2017 installation had Python/Anaconda modules installed that seemed to cause the problem for me.  My Server menu was empty.